# Cannot remove my view from its superview

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my current iOS app, I am changing the way I handle the switch betwen my welcome / login / tabbar views so it use a MainViewController (like detailed in this article: http://www.mikeziray.com/2010/01/27/handling-your-initial-view-controllers-for-iphone/comment-page-1/#comment-605)

My MainViewController is a Singleton, and contains a stack of the welcome / login / tabbar views, it also has methods to:
    - remove the welcome view from the stack
    - remove the login view from the stack

When the app starts, the welcome view is displayed and I get rid of it (calling MainViewcontroller's removeWelcomeView) when it is done checking stuff on the server.

I'm facing a strange thing though.
WelcomeViewController has the following method to remove the view from the stack (calling corresponding method in MainViewController):

```
- (void)removeView{
   [[MainViewController getInstance] removeWelcomeView];
}
```

But the following call does not work:

```
[self removeView]
```

where this call works:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(removeView)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
```

Any idea of the problem ?

Note: the method in MainViewController is the following one:

```
- (void)removeWelcomeView
{
    [welcome.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: What error do you recieve? How do you create the welcome view?

Comment: @andreas-helgegren, In fact, I do not receive any error, the welcome view is just not removed. I have created this gist to give more details: https://gist.github.com/1744267

Comment: calling removeView inside viewDidLoad may not be allowed...

Comment: @peterept: Good point! Thats maybe why it works with NSTimer

Comment: or actually, have you checked to make sure view is not null in viewDidLoad. That can happen sometimes depending on how the view controller creates it's children.

Comment: @peterept Ok, thanks, I see... so in that case the best way would probably be to not display the welcomeView for not logged user (at it will not do anything ion this case though)

Comment: @peterept for what I understand, the fact is works with NSTimer is because I'm lucky and I cannot be sure it will work each time ?

Comment: I looked at your code, and you are initializing your view controllers with init only. WHich means you probably do end up with a null view in viewDidLoad. Either load the view from a NIB or use loadView to set it up

Comment: @peterept, thanks a lot, I will make the change and keep you informed.

Comment: @peterept I replaced the init with initWithNibName but still the same problem. I cannot figure out why the NSTimer works.